# Why doesn't my generator function produce correct values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had an assignment for my programming class to write a generator function that takes an int (`n`) and a generator (`gen`) as arguments and generates the first `n` elements of the given generator. I wrote:

```
from typing import Iterator, Any

def basic_generator(n):  # Just a generator function to be able to test it out
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1

def tryout(n: int, gen: Iterator[Any]) -> Iterator[Any]:
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        next(gen)
        yield i
        i = i + 1
```

In the feedback I received it told me it's wrong but it didn't say why. I get that it doesn't work but I don't understand why. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: No sure, but the `tryout` function calls the `basic_generator` generator, but it doesn't actually use the returned value.

Answer (score 3):

You are `yield`ing the ***counter*** instead of the ***value***... Change to `yield next(gen)`.

It would also be cleaner to use a `for` loop instead of a `while`:

```py
def tryout(n: int, gen: Iterator[Any]) -> Iterator[Any]:
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(gen)
```